# Unity Netcode Pick up and Hold Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity-networking

i was trying to make a script for picking up an object and holding it/carry it in unity networking.
without networking i would just change the parent. this is not possible tho, i can only set a child to a networkobject. but the hand where i want to hold it doesn't have one, what is the best solution now?

i tried to do

```
currentHoldingItem.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().TrySetParent(holdTransform);
```

but i get an error saying `InvalidParentException: Invalid parenting, NetworkObject moved under a non-NetworkObject`

Comment: Why do you specifically need to re-parent it? Why not just parent it on the client who is holding it and sync the position? See e.g. [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) which works for Rigidbody without parenting at all

Comment: @derHugo i tried it and i hate it